# How to get the value of the grand child in firebase realtime database?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to get the child value of sender if its equal to the current logged in user.. but I was unable to get the same.

The JSON of the database is below:-

```
{
  "requests" : {
    "YJ5qTg2uuqQeicsWCTCNQMv4OwL2" : {
      "-Lecn9gN5puugx5z-PKX" : {
        "sender" : "0XWmi1Izr6XHYvqxamfNHDONSVA2",
        "status" : "Pending"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

This is what I have tried but I am always getting null.

```
this.firebase.database().ref('/requests').orderByChild('sender').equalTo(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).on('value',(snapshot) =>
    {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    })
```

But every time I am getting null.

I did understand that I should provide the child address to reach to the grand child.

```
this.firebase.database().ref('/requests').orderByChild('-Lecn9gN5puugx5z-PKX/status').equalTo('Pending').on('value',(snapshot) =>
    {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    })
```

If I am explicitly providing the child address then I am getting the value needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your callback will need to handle that list by looping of the child nodes of the result with `forEach`. So something like:

```
this.firebase.database().ref('/requests')
.orderByChild('-Lecn9gN5puugx5z-PKX/status').equalTo('Pending').on('value',(snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(child.key+': '+child.val());
  })
})
```

Comment: But how to get the grand child here status directly without having any knowledge about the child here -Lecn9gN5puugx5z-PKX

Comment: Ah wait, you're two dynamic levels deep. That sort of query is not possible. Firebase can only query child properties at a known path under each immediately child. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: Ohk thanks, can firestore help me?

Comment: Firestore just launched collection group queries, where you can query across all collections with a specific name. If that will allow the query you want is hard to say for me, but you might want to check it out.

Comment: Sure thanks for ur help.